# Move Ubuntu Server Virtual Machine from Linux to Windows

Tags: 12.10, windows, virtualbox

I've created a virtual machine under Xubuntu Linux 12.10 x86_64 and installed Ubuntu Server 12.10 x86_64 on it, then i configured it for my use case - no problems here, everything works great.

Later on, i terminated the machine and copied the virtual disk image (VDI-file) to my Windows 7 (64-bit) machine, then i re-created the virtual machine and attached image file to it. But when i try to boot it, i can't get past the GRUB menu - i see just a black window and nothing is happening.

How can i launch this machine on Windows host? Or how can i at least investigate the situation?

Answer (score 2):

I have found File -> Export Appliance followed on the other machine by File -> Import Appliance to be the best way to move virtual machines in Virtual Box.